# Unique Identifier should not change with iOS version change

Tags: ios, cocoa

I'm developing an application which is using `device unique identifier to register device with server`.
I am using `MacAddress` to get unique identifier of device, but in iOS7 it will return same(static for all device).
I found other alternate as

```
NSUUID *vendorId = [[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor];
```

But that will change as iOS device changed.
So can anyone suggest me `some unique identifier which will not change` if iOS version change it should be same for all iOS version (iOS7, iOS6).

Comment: Apple has removed the use of the `UDID` completely as you aren't allowed to gather that sort of data anymore. Apple are trying to discourage developers from trying to identify a certain user to a certain device. I believe if you read the Apple Privacy Policy it does actually have a section that indicates you aren't allowed to identify a user to a certain device at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is not allowing to use the `Device's UDID` to identify the users. So you can do it in other way.

Instead of sending the UDID to the server, create a unique Id on the server and put that ID in the application to recognize the user. In this way, you will not break the Apple's guidelines and the problem of varying the iOS versions also get resolved with this.

Comment: Technically you would actually be breaking the Apple Privacy Policy which in turn would mean you are breaking the Apple guidelines. Apple have put huge restrictions to not identify a user to a device and this is included in there Privacy Policy and as a Apple developer you have to agree too. So following your recommendation would actually still break the guidelines it would just be hard for Apple to prove it.

Comment: I already have couple of apps on the stores in which i did this. So you don't worry about that. Actually the thing is we are not harming the functionality this is just private to the app itself.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it affects functionality or not. Apple have stopped this for a reason (privacy and security reasons) and going around that isn't good. Like I said though it is harder for them to prove that you are doing this. For what reason do you need to identify a user to a device if it is private to the app. Sounds a bit fishy.

Comment: There are so many applications of this. You got the solution now, if you want this them implement or if in future you need it, you can have. Cheers. :)

Comment: Just because you can do it doesn't mean you should. The is an article on the bbc news website today about a development company in the US that has just been fined for doing this exact method of identifying users to a device. The main reason was because the user wasn't informed of this but it was also because the it went against Android and Apple privacy policy. So just because you can doesn't mean you should

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple answer: It is not possible. Here you have an overview over the identifiers: [The Developer’s Guide to Unique Identifiers](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just store the UUID into the keychain.
sskeychain refers to  https://github.com/samsoffes/sskeychain

code as following^^

```
NSString *identifier = [SSKeychain passwordForService:kSSToolkitTestsServiceName account:kSSToolkitTestsAccountName];

if (identifier != nil && [identifier length] > 0) {
    return identifier;
}

identifier = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

[SSKeychain setPassword:identifier forService:kSSToolkitTestsServiceName account:kSSToolkitTestsAccountName];
return identifier;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Apple disallows application to Uniquely identify a device (AS per them it violates User Privacy).. So you have either left with vendor ID or Advertisement ID.. another thing which you can try is that writing a web service which provides a unique ID to your app on first login and you will store that in in key chain or DB on your device..